# removeFromParent is not working in when having other functions

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, skshapenode

I am trying to write a code where balls are dropped and as soon as they get below half of the screen they get removed, so that nodes don't keep pilling up.

As the balls are generated, they are being added to a nodes array "balls", then I am removing them as needed with a `for` loop.

The interesting part is that as long as I do not have any other action in the loop, nodes are being removed properly. However when I add the flyPoints, nodes just keep on pilling up and and no longer get removed, no error though. Does anyone know why? At the same time I need to keep the fly points function in the for loop and remove the nodes. 
Thanks

```
for ball in balls {
        if ball.Ball.position.y < self.frame.height/2 {

            flyPoints(location: ball.position(), points: "+1", view: self)
            ball.Ball.removeFromParent()
            balls.removeFirst()

        }
 }
```

Comment: if I understand what you're saying correctly,  you should be calling removeFromParentNode() not removeFromParent()

Comment: hmmm... removingFromParentNode() removes the node from a parent node, in my case, ball has no node as a parent, its parent is SKScene?

Comment: I had the same issue, did you fix it @dre_84w934 ?

Comment: for me the problem was outside of this code, but basically I had created a retain cycle. here's more on that, hope it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcoZJ88d-vM